# Bind click event to D3 element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, dom-events

The following results in the method `nodeClick()` being called once upon page load (without clicking). Why? How do I make the `nodeClick()` function be triggered only when I click the element?

Code:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .on("click", nodeClick());
```

in the context:

```
var width = 960,
   height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(120)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .on("click", nodeClick()),
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");

function start() {
    link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    link.exit().remove();

    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
    node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8);
    node.exit().remove();

    force.start();
}

function nodeClick() {
    console.log("ASDASDASD");
}

function tick() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually calling the function when you're setting up the click handler. You need to attach a function to the handler that will call the function you actually want when called:

```
.on("click", function() { nodeClick() });
```

or equivalently give it the function name without calling the function (shorter)

```
.on("click", nodeClick);
```

Comment: okay, I replaced the line. Now nodeClick() is no longer called upon page load and there are no errors. However nothing happens when I click the elements. May it be because the elements are added upon user input event (not on page load)?

Comment: You would need to run the `.on("click", ...)` code inside the `start` function and whenever nodes are added/removed.