# D3 arc tweening not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to programming so apologies if the answer to this is obvious but after hours of searching I can't find out what's wrong.

I simply want to tween an arc in D3.js (in this case change the endAngle to 0). I've been through lots of examples but I must be missing something. I have built a function to change arc colour on clicking which works but it is the second function 'arcTween' to change the arc endAngle of the outermost arcs that doesn't work. Can you help?

Many thanks

Full JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vaaa052h/

Extracts below

```
var chartArea = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg") //  d3 SVG function
.attr("width", 210)
    .attr("height", 210);


var arcGroup = chartArea.append("g") //  d3 g grouping function
.attr("transform", "translate(" + transX + "," + transY + ")")
    .attr("class", "arc");


var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(function (d) {
    return radius[level];
})
    .outerRadius(function (d) {
    return radius[level + 1];
})
    .startAngle(function (d) {
    return minAngArc;
})
    .endAngle(function (d) {
    return maxAngArc;
});


////////  chart building ///////////////


arcGroup.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", color(0, random, 0, i, j, k))
    .attr("opacity", opacity(rating))
    .on("click", arcTween());

////// click functions   //////////

function arcTween(d) {
    d3.select(this).transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function (d) {
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, 0);
        return function (t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            return arc(d);
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636)?

Comment: Thank you Lars. Yes I have seen it and can copy it but when I want to update it it with my specific requirements it doesn't work - which will be due to me not understanding the detail somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a couple of changes in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/a8r326m5/1/

First, when you set up the click handler, avoid calling it on page load by using:

```
.on("click", arcTween);
```

instead of

```
.on("click", arcTween());
```

as per [Lars' explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324168/3442309).  This will stop you getting "Object [object global] has no method 'getAttribute'" errors in the console

Second, bind some data to the path elements so we can manipulate it later:

```
arcGroup.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle:maxAngArc, startAngle:minAngArc})
    ....
```

And thirdly, use this data in the `arcTween` function. By setting `maxAngArc` and `minAngArc`, and then tweening the value of `maxAngArc` to `minAngArc` (I've asumed you mean to do this rather than tweening to `0`), you should get the behaviour you want. The tween function:

```
function arcTween(d) {
    maxAngArc = d.endAngle;
    minAngArc = d.startAngle;
    d3.select(this).transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function (d) {
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.startAngle);
        return function (t) {
            maxAngArc =  interpolate(t);
            return arc(d);
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Many thanks. I'd assumed the data was already bound when attributes were assigned but this explains a lot.